# Event management in C language

Tags: c, function-pointers, event-listener

How to approach event listener mechanism in C, I am familiar with the C++ and Java. And i dint get any good approach doing with C. Preferably using Function pointers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For implementing a generic event-handling system yourself? Some specific event-handling system? Some special type of events? What have you tried so far? What have worked, and what haven't worked?

Answer (score 4):

Generally a good approach is to have a map between incoming event and callback functions (functions pointers): For example something like this:

```
static const event_handling_map_t event_handling_map[] = {
      {EVENT1,           handle_event_1},
      {EVENT2,           handle_event_2},
      {EVENT3,           handle_event_3}
  }
```

where the handle_event are functions that should handle the specific event.
So when an event is received, the specific function can be used, for example (assume that EVENT1 is defined in an enum and it has value 0), the function will be called like this:

```
event_handling_map[EVENT1].handle_events_cb(args);
```

The `handle_event_cb` will be `handle_event_1` in this case.